# Issue with switching the up and down glyph icons when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the live code to play with:

http://www.bootply.com/fAR3pUSRXq

When the accordion is expanded, I do want the arrow to be pointing "**UP**" which  it is already. BUT when I click it to collapse the accordion, I want the arrow to be now pointing "**down**" BUT it still stays **up**.*So I want the behaviour to be reverse! when accordion is open , point up !, when accordion is closed, point down.* 
 what is the issue?  Thanks for help.

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482863/get-the-element-that-was-collapsed-on-hidden-shown-bs-collapse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

JS:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $("span").addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });

$('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $("span").addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  });
```

See [Bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/B3JecPBpTu)

Comment: Looks like it is working, what was I doing wrong ? :)

Comment: wouldn't `toggleClass` work better? `$('.collapse').on('click', () => $('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down');`